# Unable to install 'Dart-Code.flutter' in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I need to install flutter in VS Code but in install extension, I have 
this error

```
Unable to install 'Dart-Code.flutter'; there is no available versioncompatible 
with VS Code '1.20.1'.
```

VS Code version 1.20.1 is version compatible for flutter :

https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/#vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update VS Code to 1.23.1 and install flutter and the problem was solved!

Comment: Sorry about the misleading version on the website. It was correct at the time it was written but we often bump the required version in order to get new APIs we need from VS Code. I've [opened a PR to tweak this text](https://github.com/flutter/website/pull/1068) to just say we require the latest stable version, which is usually the case.